# Cookie set/read does not work consistently (first one works, second one doesn´t)

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, cookies

came across another weird problem.
First of all, i used search but didn´t find exactly what i needed, so i made a new question. feel free to link an answer i did not find on my own.

I´m working on a Sharepoint React project. so i got sp´s backend and my dev server running (perhaps this is important, since chrome acts differently while loading from local machine).

I wrote a service that fetches configuration data for my app from a sp list. i don´t want the app to always load the configuration on startup and for that i use cookies. Thing is, in my service class i got 2 functions, which either load from sp and set the cookie or read from cookie, if available. first function (loadConfig) works fine, cookie can be set and read and i can see it in chrome settings. Second one (loadNavConfig) is supposed to do the same, but the cookie is always undefined and i can´t find it in chrome setting. that´s pretty weird imho and i honestly have no idea, what´s causing that problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
public static getMCSConfig(): Promise<IMCSConfig> {
    return new Promise<IMCSConfig>(async (resolve) => {
        let data: IMCSConfig;
        let cookieData = MCSCookieService.get(mcsConfigCookieKey);
        if (cookieData) {
            data = JSON.parse(cookieData);
        } else {
            data = await this.loadMCSConfig();
            MCSCookieService.set(mcsConfigCookieKey, JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        MCSNavNodeConfigService.initConfig(data);
        resolve(data);
    });
}

private static loadNavigationNodeConfig():Promise<Array<INavigationNode>> {
    return new Promise<Array<INavigationNode>>(async (resolve)=>{
        let items: any;
        let cookieData = MCSCookieService.get(mcsNavNodeConfigCookieKey);
        if (cookieData) { // undefined
            items = JSON.parse(cookieData);
        } else {
            items = await web.lists.getByTitle(mcsNavNodeConfigTitle).items.select("FileRef,*").getAll();
            MCSCookieService.set(mcsNavNodeConfigCookieKey, JSON.stringify(items)); // doesn´t work
        }
// .... and so on
    });
}
```

expected: cookie set/read works consistent
actual result: first cookie set/read works, second cookie doesnt

Comment: Could you paste the response to this in your question?
items = await web.lists.getByTitle(mcsNavNodeConfigTitle).items.select("FileRef,*").getAll()

Comment: dunno, it´s just an array containing 165 objects. those have properties, like FileSystemObjectType, Id, ContentTypeId and such. no error is thrown in console, i just don´t get it xD also those are flat objects, so i don´t see a problem there